# Selective running of tests in HUnit

Tags: unit-testing, haskell

`Test.HUnit` provides a big red button to run a test:

```
runTestTT :: Test -> IO Counts
```

As there is a need to structure large test suites, `Test` is not a single test but is actually a labelled rose tree with `Assertion` in leaves:

```
data Test
  = TestCase Assertion | TestList [Test] | TestLabel String Test
        -- Defined in `Test.HUnit.Base'
```

It's not abstract so it's possible to process it. One particularly useful processing is extraction of subtrees by paths:

```
byPath = flip $ foldl f where
    f (TestList l) = (l !!)
    f (TestLabel _ t) = const t
    f t = const t
```

So for example I can run a single subsuite `runTestTT $ byPath [1] tests` or a particular test `runTestTT $ byPath [1,7,3] tests` identified by test path instead of waiting for whole suite.

One disadvantage of the homegrown tool is that test paths are not preserved (shortened).

Is there such processing helper tool already on Hackage?

Answer (score 2):

The closest to your needs seem to be the libraries and programs that abstract over HUnit, Quickcheck and other tests, and have their own test name grouping and management infrastructure, e.g. [test-framework](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework). It provides you with a `main` function that takes command line arguments, including one that allows you to specify a test or test group to run (by globbing on the name).